# Why isn't Mypy inferring a 3rd-part library function's type?

Tags: python, django, type-inference, mypy, pyright

Considering this code:

```py
class ExportView(IndexView):
    model_admin: Optional[ModelAdmin] = None

    def export_csv(self) -> HttpResponse | StreamingHttpResponse:
        fields = getattr(self.model_admin, "csv_export_fields", [])
        return render_to_csv_response(self.queryset.all().values(*fields))
```

I get the following error from Mypy on the `return` line:

> error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Union[HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse]"  [no-any-return]

`render_to_csv_response` is [a method from django-queryset-csv](https://github.com/azavea/django-queryset-csv/blob/master/djqscsv/djqscsv.py#L33), and Pyright correctly infer its return type as being a `Union[HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse]`.

I thought that Mypy was not reading the 3rd-part library, as if running with `--follow-imports=skip`, but my `pyproject.toml` config has set `silent`, which [behaves in the same way as normal](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#following-imports)

```ini
[tool.mypy]
plugins = ["mypy_django_plugin.main"]
disallow_untyped_defs = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
follow_imports = 'silent'
no_incremental = true
warn_redundant_casts = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unreachable = true
enable_error_code = 'ignore-without-code'
show_error_codes = true
```

Changing it to `normal` doesn't fix the issue either.
Any idea how to get Mypy to find the proper type, like Pyright does out of the box?

Comment: Pyright generally analyses all imported files to determine type information. [For performance reasons](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17945#issuecomment-928798977), MyPy doesn't do this. As far as I am aware, if a dependency doesn't have its type hints explicitly marked or doesn't contian typing information in `.pyi` files, it will assume that the return values of all non-trivial functions are `any`. You're probably best off adding a `# type: ignore` comment to the line.